# Problem to install Fancontrol with Ubuntu 22.04 and MSI motherboard

Tags: fancontrol, msi, sensors, lm-sensors

I wanted to control my fan speed with the fancontrol package. I soon run into this problem:

`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

After a bit of research, I realised that I need to add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to `/etc/default/grub`

Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. I did more research and checked my `sensors`, which gave me the following output:

```
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +37.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 16:       +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 20:       +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 24:       +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 28:       +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 32:       +36.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 33:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 34:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 35:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 36:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 37:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 38:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 39:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 40:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 41:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 42:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 43:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 44:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 45:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 46:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 47:       +35.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +39.0°C  

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +45.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +79.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +45.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
```

As one can see, there is no fan information. When running `sensors-detect` and agreeing to everything, I get the following output:

```
To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!
```

I have the impression that there should be another driver listed after coretemp, but could not find any solution for that. Therefore, I kindly ask the forum for help :-)

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer. I use the MSI MPG Z790 motherboard. Further, I have 2 RTX3090 GPUs with the 525 driver.

Edit: Here the output of the super I/O section from the `sensors-detect` command.

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0xd592
```

Comment: post the output of the Super I/O section when running `sensors-detect`

Comment: @rtaft Thank you for your help. I have added the information to the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the information here

```
Found unknown chip with ID 0xd592
```

When you search for that exact error, you will find some resources to help.
It looks like this board has a I/O Controller NUVOTON NCT6687-R Controller Chip.  The good news is that drivers for older Nuvoton controllers will probably work with it if we manually load them.  You can see the `nct` drivers available https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/hwmon

Inside `nct6683.c` we see

```
#define SIO_NCT6687_ID      0xd590
```

It looks like support was added for it in 5.11 under `nct6683`, and Ubuntu 22.04 started with 5.15 and now uses 5.19 so it should work in all 22.04 versions. It must be an issue with `sensors-detect`.

Test it out with

```
sudo modprobe nct6683
```

and see if it shows up in `sensors`.  If it works, simply add `nct6683` on it's own line in `/etc/modules`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it out but it did not work. So I assume it is a driver problem. I checked on the MSI page, but they did not provide any Linux drivers. Do you have any suggestion where else I could source another driver, given that the old one also doesn't work?

Comment: Did you rebuild grub after adding lax to /etc/default/grub?

Comment: You can also try `sudo modprobe -f nct6683`.  There is a check in the driver to see if the `customer_id` for the board matches what it expects (0x201 for MSI).  It's possible it's using something else, in which the `-f` will bypass it.

Comment: I've done rebuild on grub and tested the `sudo modprobe -f nct6683` command. Still not working.

Comment: does `grep nct /etc/sensors3.conf` have an entry for `nct6683` or `nct6687`?  I encountered this chip previously on here on an MSI Z590 and a simple modprobe worked, odd that it's not working here.

Comment: Can't hurt to post the line from grub that you updated, make sure it looks right.  I don't think that is the issue though.

Comment: `grep nct /etc/sensors3.conf` gives as results `chip "w83627ehf-*" "w83627dhg-*" "w83667hg-*" "nct6775-*" "nct6776-*" \
     "nct6779-*" "nct6791-*" "nct6795-*" "nct6796-*"`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas.  There is a sample sensors3.conf entry at https://github.com/Fred78290/nct6687d you can try, if that doesnt work, could try the driver on that page.